# AngularJs filter sql timestamp "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss" to something else

Tags: angularjs

I've tried the angular docs of {{someDate | date:'params'}}, however; This doesn't work if someDate is in this format yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.

How would I convert yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss to say just yyyy using angularjs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The date filter is designed to handle [multiple input types](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/date) including date objects and common date strings. If your date string is not recognized by the provided date filter, I would just write my own filter. It would look something like this...

```
myapp.filter('toYear', function () {
     return function (dateString) {
         var dateObject = new Date(dateString);
         return dateObject.getFullYear();
     };
});
```

You can use it like this...

```
{{someDate | toYear}}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can define a custom format as follows

```
Date.prototype.customFormat = function(){
    return this.getMonth() + 
    "/" +  this.getDate() +
    "/" +  this.getFullYear();
}

//usage

> var d = new Date()
Fri Mar 14 2014 15:39:07 GMT+0000 (GMT Standard Time)
> d.customFormat()
'2/14/2014'
```

More details https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/DateTimeFormat

Answer (score 0):

I actually fixed the solution here:

```
app.filter('timestampToISO', function() {
    return function(input) {
        input = new Date(input).toISOString();
        return input;
    };
});
```

http://bit.ly/1iJAV8G

UPDATE:

To implement you add this to the view:

```
{{someSQLTIMESTAMP | timestampToISO | date}}
```

Comment: Ah very nice. Now you can just do...
{{someDate | timestampToISO | date:'yyyy'}}

Answer (score 0):

Angular js date object doesn't support to convert from MySql date format to timestamp directly. So need to convert it to acceptable format from `YYYY-mm-dd H:i:s` to `YYYY/mm/dd H:i:s` and then convert it to a timestamp.

You may try the below snippet to convert Mysql date format `YYYY-mm-dd H:i:s` to timestamp using AngularJs filter

```
app.filter("mysqlDateFormatToTimestamp", function(){
    return function(date){
        var date1 =  date2 = date3 = timestamp = hours = minutes = seconds = '';               
        date1 = date.split(':'); 
        date2 = date1[0].split(' '); 
        date3 = date2[0].split('-'); // Change it based on your format
        if( date1.length == 1 && date2.length == 1 ){
            hours = '00';
            minutes = '00';
            seconds = '00';
        }else{
            hours = parseInt(date2[1]);
            minutes = parseInt(date1[1]);
            seconds = parseInt(date1[2]);
        } 
        timestamp = new Date(parseInt(date3[0]), parseInt(date3[1])-1, parseInt(date3[2]), hours, minutes, seconds);
        return timestamp;
   } 
});
```

Now, You may use this filter wherever the date format you want, and you may change the params as you like.

```
   {{ '2016-07-07 05:27:30' | mysqlDateFormatToTimestamp | date:'LLLL dd, yyyy HH:mm:ss'}} 
   // results would comes like "July 07, 2016 05:27:30"

   {{ '2016-07-07 05:27:30' | mysqlDateFormatToTimestamp | date:'yyyy'}} 
   // results would comes like "2016"
```